# Rails server keep failing. NoMethodError `new_with_config'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I installed rails recently and I have been having quite a bit of trouble just trying to install everything, but it is finally done and now when I try to launch a rails server I always get an error and the server ends up stoping at that exact moment.

Here is what it says:

> NoMethodError `new_with_config' for
>   ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:Class.

I am using Rails version 5.0.0.1

Comment: Are you using gems aside from the default Rails gems? Do you have the same error when generating a fresh Rails app?

Comment: Have you installed any gem explicitly? follow this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/116